# Swapping NSViews using a push transition

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, core-animation, nsview

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but I can't seem to get it. How would I swap two NSViews using a push transition (like what UINavigationController does on iOS)? What I've tried so far:

- Using an NSAnimation subclass **<-- too slow**
- Using NSViewAnimation and MGViewAnimation **<-- too slow**
- Using the NSView animator proxy **<-- too slow**
- Using CATransition **<-- I can't use this because CATransition requires the views to be layer backed, and layer backing views causes text rendering glitches as well as various other graphical artifacts**

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see why the first three are too slow?

Comment: I'd be going with your first or second choice.  There must be some reason it's slow for you.  I swap views in and out with animations (in all of 0.2 seconds) and they go nice and snappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the animation is slow because I'm animating a pretty large view. I don't think there's any way around that other than the good old image swap trick (taking an image of the view and animating that instead of the view itself).

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 options are probably too slow because you're trying to use them without layer-backing your views. To do animation in AppKit, you're going to need to have your views backed by layers.